# importing selected columns of csv file in different sql tables using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

My csv file looks like this:

```
Name | DateOfBirth| Gender| Occupation| DateOfTest | FieldNumber | Eye | ThresholdValue

Fred, 12/08/68,M, carpenter, 12/02/06, 1, R, 1234
Susan, 3/09/72, F, hairstylist, 12/04/07, 1, R, 1234
Fred, 12/08/68,M, carpenter, 12/02/06, 1, L, 1234
Susan, 3/09/72, F, hairstylist, 12/04/07, 1, L, 1234
Fred, 12/08/68,M, carpenter, 12/02/08, 1, R, 1234
Susan, 3/09/72, F, hairstylist, 12/04/08, 1, R, 1234
Fred, 12/08/68,M, carpenter, 12/02/08, 1, L, 1234
Susan, 3/09/72, F, hairstylist, 12/04/08, 1, L, 1234
```

Each patient will have two rows(for left and right eye) for each instance of test undertaken by them and they can undertake multiple tests. I have to put this information in a database in a way that it can be extracted from different dimensions like analyse data from all females, or analyse data from all carpenters etc. I thought of following two tables:

```
Patient_info
PatientID(auto-increment primary key), name, dob, gender, occupation 

test_info
testID(auto-increment primary key), patientID(foreign key from patient_info), dot, fieldnumber, eye, thresholdvalue
```

I have been able to populate patient_info table by using fgetcsv() function of php. $sql works fine but $sql2 does not.

```
<?php



    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
    include "connection.php";

    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE patient_info";
    mysql_query($deleterecords);

    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE test_info";
    mysql_query($deleterecords);    

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $handle = fopen($file,"r");

        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $name = $fileop[0];
            $dateofbirth = $fileop[1];
            $gender = $fileop[2];
            $occupation = $fileop[3];
            $dateoftest = $fileop[4];
            $field = $fileop[5];
            $eye = $fileop[6];
            $thresholdvalues = $fileop[7];
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO patient_info (Name, DateOfBirth, Gender, Occupation) VALUES ('$name','$dateofbirth','$gender','$occupation')" );
            $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_info (DateOfTest, FieldNumber, Eye, ThresholdValues) VALUES   ('$dateoftest','$field','$eye','$thresholdvalues')" );

        }
            fclose($handle);
            if($sql2) { echo 'test data successfully uploaded';}

            if($sql) 
            {
                echo 'Data uploaded successfully';
                header("Location: http://localhost/lei/test.com/proper/upload_page.php");
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Upload Failed';
            }

    }

?>
```

Questions:
1) How can I insert just one record for each patient in patient_info table, but multiple records for each instance of test undertaken by the patient in test_info table??
2) How should I populate test_info table using patientID from patient_info table and other values from csv file?
3) I want to empty both the tables every time a new csv file is uploaded. I was using TRUNCATE query to do that, but since I defined PatientID as foreign key, TRUNCATE does not work. How can I empty both the tables before uploading a new csv file?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @u_mulder That works fine. Thanks a lot ! But got another question now, plz check the edit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why use PHP for this at all?  I'd do it all natively within SQL:

1. Define your tables (if not already done).  Note that you must define a uniqueness constraint over the relevant columns in `patient_info` by which you will identify matching patients from your CSV data:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE patient_info (
     PatientID      SERIAL,
     Name           VARCHAR(255),
     DateOfBirth    DATE,
     Gender         ENUM('M','F'),
     Occupation     VARCHAR(255),
     UNIQUE(Name, DateOfBirth, Gender, Occupation)
   );

   CREATE TABLE test_info (
     TestID         SERIAL,
     PatientID      BIGINT UNSIGNED,
     DateOfTest     DATE,
     FieldNumber    INT UNSIGNED,
     Eye            ENUM('R','L'),
     ThresholdValue INT UNSIGNED,
     FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES patient_info (PatientID)
   );
   ```
2. Define a table into which you will import the raw CSV data:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE import (
     Name           VARCHAR(255),
     DateOfBirth    DATE,
     Gender         ENUM('M','F'),
     Occupation     VARCHAR(255),
     DateOfTest     DATE,
     FieldNumber    INT UNSIGNED,
     Eye            ENUM('R','L'),
     ThresholdValue INT UNSIGNED
   );
   ```
3. Define an `AFTER INSERT` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that will split the imported data and perform the relevant insertions into your "real" tables.  You can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) together with [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to obtain the `PatientID` of each record, even if it already exists:

   ```sql
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE TRIGGER trig AFTER INSERT ON import FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     INSERT INTO patient_info (
       Name,
       DateOfBirth,
       Gender,
       Occupation
     ) VALUES (
       NEW.Name,
       NEW.DateOfBirth,
       NEW.Gender,
       NEW.Occupation
     ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       PatientID = LAST_INSERT_ID(PatientID)
     ;

     INSERT INTO test_info (
       PatientID,
       DateOfTest,
       FieldNumber,
       Eye,
       ThresholdValue
     ) VALUES (
       LAST_INSERT_ID(),
       NEW.DateOfTest,
       NEW.FieldNumber,
       NEW.Eye,
       NEW.ThresholdValue
     );
   END//
   DELIMITER ;
   ```
4. Import the data:

   ```sql
   LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
     INTO TABLE import
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   ;
   ```
5. Tidy up:

   ```sql
   DROP TRIGGER trig;
   DROP TABLE import;
   ```

   Or alternatively (depending on whether you intend to reuse it in the future):

   ```sql
   TRUNCATE import;
   ```

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin to create my tables and the file is uploaded from user end on a webpage i.e. I was using php for reading in the file and populating tables. But with your solution, how can I TRUNCATE both the patient_info and test_info table if a new csv file is uploaded, it gives an error cause of foreign key.